# Session User login problem, when I wake-up my Laptop from suspend

Tags: users, login-screen, session, logout

After I upgraded to 13.10, there are many few problem about login when I wake-up from suspend, after I have done the other activity.

Illustration:
When I wake-up from suspend in my laptop and I login and enter my password on it, then I use for my activity (like surfing, make documnets, etc). After approximately 5 - 10 seconds in activity, it turned back into blank screen and log-out automatically itself suddenly.

Can anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding I think it has something to do with Lock-screen, and **IF** that is the case then you just have to go to system settings -> Brightness and lock -> change the lock into never or set time for it. **IF** it has nothing to do with screen lock then I'm sorry I get your question wrong.